# How to train/develop photographic memory?

Tags: memory, working-memory

In this [older post](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4564/is-photographic-memory-possible), @Beofett asked whether photographic memory (I don't really know if this is the correct term) was even possible...

For me, **photographic memory** is the impressing ability to remember things or events (such as colors, pictures, numbers, etc.) in great detail, i.e. being able to describe things you've seen or listened to in a very detailed way.

I know one girl in my class, who has doubtless the ability to remember a lot of things with a single look which I definitively find awesome!

This is the reason why I was asking myself, whether it's possible to develop and train this photographic memory and if so **how**?

PS: I've already done some research on the internet; however, I don't know if the webpage's sources are reliable or not, so I hope that the experts of this site can help;)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. You said *"I've already done some research on the internet; however, I don't know if the webpage's sources are reliable or not"*. Could you please provide links to the webpages you are questioning so we can appraise them in an answer? It also shows us what you **have** read on the subject.